# assert((df->type & ~(CT_OBSTACLE | CT_FLUID | CT_INTERFACE | CT_EMPTY)) == 0)

Tags: c

What does `&`, `~` and `==0` means in this assertion? Is it saying remove tags from type variables? I am not familiar with the `C` and `C++` languages. Just learning by reading code.

Comment: This might help:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxt4z71k.aspx
But what is df declared to be ?

Comment: @icbytes Microsoft is a poor source to learn C programming from. I have never heard of the "one's complement operator" before: nobody calls it that. It is formally named the _bitwise complement operator_ (see 6.5.3.3 of the standard).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To translate the C code into English, it means "if any of the bits that aren't one of CT_OBSTACLE, CT_FLUID etc... are set in variable `df->type`, then throw an assertion".

`df->type` is a bit field and `CT_EMPTY`etc are bit masks. `|` (bitwise OR) forms a new, temporary bit mask out of these four bit masks. For example if they are 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08 you would get a mask 0x0F.

This temporary mask is then inverted with the bitwise complement operator `~`. So if the mask was 0x0F, it is now 0xF0.

And finally the bit field variable `df->type` is compared against the mask with bitwise AND `&`, to see if any of the bits were set. Note that since the mask was inverted, this checks all bits that aren't CT_OBSTACLE etc. The final result is compared against zero.

I would guess this is some sort of defensive programming to ensure that bits that have no functionality aren't set.

Comment: or it would be that df->type is not expected to be any of those values ORed in the assertion

Comment: Thanks. Now I got it.

Answer (score 1):

`&` and `~` are two different operators:

```
`&` is the bitwise AND operator.
`~` is the bitwise negation operator.
```

`==` is the equal to operator (equality check).

By looking at those mask constants you got there, it seems the whole point of the assertion is to make sure that `df->type` doesn't have anything outside those 4 bit masks set.

Answer (score 1):

This is basic of masking using **bitwise** operations. In order to understand this, you should at least know binary representation of value

Best is to show the concept by example, suppose

```
#define CT_OBSTACLE  0x08 //binary representation: 0000 1000
#define CT_FLUID     0x04 //binary representation: 0000 0100
#define CT_INTERFACE 0x02 //binary representation: 0000 0010
#define CT_EMPTY     0x01 //binary representation: 0000 0001
```

And then `|` is called **bitwise-or**. It sees the logic in the binary representation just like what and `OR` in math boolean logic will do.

Thus,

```
CT_OBSTACLE | CT_FLUID | CT_INTERFACE | CT_EMPTY
```

will give you

```
0000 1000
0000 0100
0000 0010
0000 0001
--------- OR
0000 1111 = 0x0F
```

Then `~` is **bitwise-negation** it inverts 0 and 1 in the binary representation. Hence,

```
~(CT_OBSTACLE | CT_FLUID | CT_INTERFACE | CT_EMPTY)
```

will give you

```
0000 1111 //original
1111 0000 //inverted! = 0xf0
```

Next, `&` is called **bitwise-and** it is similar concept to **bitwise-or** except that the logic used now is **AND**

Thus, supposing `dt->type = 0xC3 = 1100 0011 (in binary)`, then

```
df->type & ~(CT_OBSTACLE | CT_FLUID | CT_INTERFACE | CT_EMPTY)
```

will give you

```
1111 0000 
1100 0011
--------- AND
1100 0000 = 0xC0
```

and lastly, `==` is just **equality comparator** as contrast to `=` which is called **assignment**. `==` is to compare if the value in the left hand side is equal to the value in the right hand side. In C. the result will be either 1 if it is true and 0 if it is false. So using the example,

```
(df->type & ~(CT_OBSTACLE | CT_FLUID | CT_INTERFACE | CT_EMPTY)) == 0
```

will result in `false` since `0xC0` is **not** equal to `0`.

Hope this can help you to get the idea!

Update: see comment to get the short answer of what the whole expression really means to the programmer/user/reader

Comment: really a short answer

Comment: Short answer updated, previous one was wrong: `type` member of the object that `df` points to is nothing, or is any of those four types.

Comment: Thanks. Very nice explanation.

Comment: Glad that you find it useful.