# How does the condition (type & ~(R_OK|W_OK|X_OK|F_OK)) work in C?

Tags: c

What kind of condition is used here and how does it works in C?

> `(type & ~(R_OK|W_OK|X_OK|F_OK))`

Found it here.

```
/* Test for access to FILE.  */
int
__access (const char *file, int type)
{
  if (file == NULL || (type & ~(R_OK|W_OK|X_OK|F_OK)) != 0)
    {
      __set_errno (EINVAL);
      return -1;
    }
  __set_errno (ENOSYS);
  return -1;
}
stub_warning (access)
```

https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/io/access.c.html

Comment: Seems to be `R_OK|W_OK|X_OK|F_OK` are macro for each status and are represented by setting a certain bits.

Comment: In order, do you understand what `|` does?  What `~` does?  What `&` does?

Comment: See [Bitwise_logic_operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Bitwise_logic_operators)

Comment: It checks that the `type` argument to `__access()` does not contain any bits that aren't in the 4 constants.

Comment: These particular bit masks is for some *nix file handling API that I don't recall the details of. But in general terms, if we have a number of single bit masks, then `MASK1 | MASK2 | MASK3` gives all of them and `~` gives a bit mask with them set to zero. So basically the code is saying "if type is not one of these: MASK1 MASK2 or MASK3".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [assert((df->type & ~(CT\_OBSTACLE | CT\_FLUID | CT\_INTERFACE | CT\_EMPTY)) == 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34415167/assertdf-type-ct-obstacle-ct-fluid-ct-interface-ct-empty-0)

Comment: Take a book and paper and pencil, and figure out what the `&`,  `~` and `|` operators do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression uses [bitwise arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation).

`a | b | c …`  creates a value that has all the bits of `a`, `b`, `c` … set.

In your piece of code, `R_OK` etc. are [bit flags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field) that each have a single, distinct bit set. Their disjunction (= or-ing them together) thus has all their bits set, and none other.

`~ x` inverts the bits of a value. Thus, the result of the operation has all bits set *except* those of `R_OK` etc.

Finally, `a & b` sets only those bits which are set in *both* `a` *and* `b`. All other bits will be 0.

The expression, taken together, thus tests whether the variable `type` has any bits set which are *not* defined by `R_OK` etc. In other words: it tests whether `test`’s value is one of `R_OK` etc., or a combination of these values. If that is not the case (i.e. if it has some *other* value), the test fails.

The function you’ve posted thus test whether it has received valid arguments (i.e. that `file` is not `NULL`, and that `test` is a valid combination of supported flags). Beyond this, the function does nothing except set an error status and return -1. And the reason for this weird behaviour can be seen in the last line: the function you’ve posted is a *stub*, it does not actually implement a proper POSIX `access` function.